# html/template: pattern matches no files even with absolute path

Tags: go

I have a global constant like this.

```
const TemplateDir string = "/home/joe/go/src/proj/template/"
```

Then, later in my code I call this.

```
template.ParseGlob(filepath.Join(TemplateDir, "*.tmpl"))
```

I know that `filepath.Join(TemplateDir, "*.tmpl")` produces `/home/joe/go/src/proj/template/*.tmpl`.

This all compiles fine. However, when I try to run my executable from a directory outside of `proj`, I get this error.

```
html/template: pattern matches no files: `template/*.tmpl`
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting that error if I passed in an absolute path. Any ideas?

**Update**
I forgot to mention that I'm calling my program through the $PATH variable. That is, I'm not executing `./proj` anywhere. I'm just calling `proj` from my home directory.

Comment: You haven't provided us with a reproducible error: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that the version I was calling using my `$PATH` variable was outdated! Here's what happened.

```
src/proj$ go build
src/proj$ ./proj
```

That would work fine, but this wouldn't work.

```
~/$ proj
```

That's because I forgot to `go install` my package! After doing `go install` in my package directory, I could call my program from anywhere.